# Exporting grid line nodes with ELEV attributes as data frame?

Tags: qgis, r, elevation, altitude, nodes

I would like to have a data frame of nrow x ncol where nrow = rows of my grid lines and ncol = col of my grid lines. The purpose is to use the ELEV data for 3D topography modeling in R.

This is what I'm looking at:

[image]

How can I export the node attributes in that same disposition?

Comment: what about saving your node layer as csv and then load it in R? You can do it by right click on the layer, save as and choose ``csv`` as output format

Comment: What you want? A data frame or a matrix? They are very different.

Answer (score 1):

In **QGIS:**

The first step is save your layer **alt_pts** to a *Comma Separeted Value* format file. To do this, just do *right click* over your layer and *Save as*. Give the file destination folder and name of the file and in *Layer options* specify *AS_XY* in the *GEOMETRY* box.

In **R:**

```
# Load data
df <- read.csv("/path/to/alt_pts.csv", header = TRUE)

# Print first six rows
head(df)

# To convert the data frame to a SpatialPointsDataFrame object

# Load library
library('sp')

# Convert object
dfSPDF <- df
coordinates(dfSPDF) <- c("X","Y") 

# Plot
spplot(dfSPDF, zcol = "ELEV") # In case your elevation column name is called 'ELEV'

# If you want to see your data interactively and over a base map use the great package mapview 

library('mapview')    
mapview(dfSPDF, zcol = "ELEV")

# Convert to SpatialPixelsDataFrame

> SpatialPixelsDataFrame(dfSPDF, data = dfSPDF@data) # get tolerance
suggested tolerance minimum: 0.116184 

# Apply suggested tolerance (sometimes it's not needed)
dfSPixDF <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(dfSPDF, data = dfSPDF@data, tolerance =  0.116184)
```

Comment: This works fine and I can produce a map in R with mapview package. By clicking on the new map I get info for that exact point i.e. X,Y and ELEV. 

How can I extract that info in order to produce a data frame with nrows = X coords and ncol = Y coords and where the values = ELEV, i.e. the data behind the map and not necessarily the map itself. 

(mapview is a great package)

Comment: Try `SpatialPixelsDataFrame` or just `gridded(dfSPDF) <- TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `as.data.frame()` from `raster` package (obviously, before you need to load your shapefile with `readOGR()` or `shapefile()`, from `rgdal`
 and `raster`packages).

Here an example

```
# Reproducible example

set.seed(1331)
pts = cbind(1:5, 1:5)
dimnames(pts)[[1]] = letters[1:5]
df = data.frame(a = 1:5,b = 2:6, c=3:7, d= letters[1:5])
row.names(df) = letters[5:1]

library(sp)
points <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(pts, df) 

# Here you convert points file
df <- as.data.frame(points)

# a, b, c and d are your fields, coords.x1 coords.x2 are x and y
   a b c d coords.x1 coords.x2 
a 1 2 3 a         1         1
b 2 3 4 b         2         2
c 3 4 5 c         3         3
d 4 5 6 d         4         4
e 5 6 7 e         5         5
```